# Time Complexity Check

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

```cpp
int n;
int b =1000;
for (int i=b;i<=n; i++)
{
    for (int j=3*i;j<=n;j++)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<=b; i++)
       {
        printf("hello\n");
       }
    }
}
```

Would the big O estimate for this be `O(n^2)`? The first loop is `O(n)`, second loop is `O(N/3)` and third loop is `O(1)`.

Comment: Sounds right to me, although it's a little weird to see `int n;` declared like that--seems like it should be a parameter. As written, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: haha yeah, sorry i meant for the n to be some value higher than b

Comment: If it's defined in the function then it'd be constant time, so I think it has to be a parameter or otherwise runtime-defined for the time complexity to make sense. Its actual runtime value wouldn't change the time complexity of the algorithm anyway, so even if it was lower than `b` during runtime, the algorithm still has the same complexity.

Comment: `for (int j=3*i;j<=n;i++)`, are you sure there's `i++` in the increment condition and not `j++`?

Comment: oh yes, it it is j++. typo sorry!