# Time complexity of triple nested loop

Tags: performance, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops, infinite-loop

```
        int n;
        int b =1000;
        for (int i=b;i<=n; i++)
        {
            for (int j=3*i;j<=n;j++)
            {
              for(i=0; i<=b; i++)
               {
                printf("hello\n");
               }
            }
        }
```

would this function be an non-terminating loop since the inner loop always sets the i back to B, thus the outer loop never ends? What would be the time complexity for something like this?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915375/time-complexity-check

Comment: The outer loop doesn't even run once, because n is initialized by default to 0.

Comment: And the inner loop's i is different from the outer i because the "int i" hides the outer i.

Comment: alrite sorry, lets pretend n is some large value. The i in the inner loop is actually just i=1 as it was a type. I have changed it